# Removing dupes in list of lists in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

Basically, I'm trying to do remove any lists that begin with the same value. For example, two of the below begin with the number 1:

```
a = [[1,2],[1,0],[2,4],[3,5]]
```

Because the value 1 exists at the start of two of the lists -- I need to remove both so that the new list becomes:

```
b = [[2,4],[3,5]]
```

How can I do this?

I've tried the below, but the output is: `[[1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 5]]`

```
def unique_by_first_n(n, coll):
    seen = set()
    for item in coll:
        compare = tuple(item[:n])
        print compare   # Keep only the first `n` elements in the set
        if compare not in seen:
            seen.add(compare)
            yield item

a = [[1,2],[1,0],[2,4],[3,5]]

filtered_list = list(unique_by_first_n(1, a))
```

Comment: 2 also exists in both. Why don't you remove them?

Comment: good point -- i only need to remove where the first item is the same. so just the 1 in this case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter` with list comprehension to get sublists whose first item appears only once:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(n for n, _ in a)
b = [[x, y] for x, y in a if c[x] == 1]
```

Comment: that sounds overcomplicated

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre its basically `[[x,y] for key, counterValue in counterItems if counterValue == 1 for x, y in my_list if x == key]`

Comment: what annoys me is the double loop. The other answer has less O complexity (and also your rewrite with new variable names is clearer)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Indeed thanks. I've fixed my answer accordingly, although it is now admittedly the same as Joe's answer.

Comment: since it seems to be the best way, I don't see a problem. I just didn't want people copy an unefficient answer (even if it worked).

Answer (score 6):

An efficient solution would be to create a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=namedtuple#collections.Counter) object to hold the occurrences of the first elements, and then filter the sub-lists in the main list:

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(l[0] for l in a)
filtered = [l for l in a if counts[l[0]] == 1]
#[[2, 4], [3, 5]]
```

Comment: `filtered = [l for l in a if counts[l[0]] == 1]` is probably clearer but yes.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Fair enough. Do you understand the logic in blhsing's answer? It certainly doesn't guarantee the order of the list is maintained.

Comment: no I don't but I see a loop which makes the solution overcomplex

Answer (score 6):

If you are happy to use a 3rd party library, you can use Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

a = [[1,2],[1,0],[2,4],[3,5]]

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
b = df.drop_duplicates(subset=[0], keep=False).values.tolist()

print(b)

[[2, 4], [3, 5]]
```

The trick is the `keep=False` argument, described in the docs for [`pd.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

Comment: I never used pandas, always did things like that manually, like the other answers but THIS is another level of readability -> sparked my interest in the library -> have a +1

Comment: @FabianN., I certainly don't recommend Pandas as a means of *learning*, but vectorised operations do have their use. And I would be disappointed to make people believe Python `list` + `dict` are the only way to structure data!

Comment: never used pandas myself, but I'm pretty sure it beats the pure python answers in terms of speed (well, don't count the `import pandas` part obviously :)

Comment: @FabianN. You should also checkout `numpy` - very fast, especially on large data sets like when image processing.

Comment: @JoeIddon I'm aware of numpy, I think that's the main reason I always ignored pandas. For simple things, I just used native python and for vectorized operations I used numpy so I never felt it was worth the effort to put even more layers on top... but from what I see above, with pandas, one can write code that's almost a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

```
a = [[1,2],[1,0],[2,4],[3,5]]
b = []
for item in a:
    i = 0
    if item[0] == a[i][0]:
        i =+ 1
        continue
    else:
        b.append(item)
        i += 1
```

**Solution 2**

```
a = [[1,2],[1,0],[2,4],[3,5]]
b = []

for item in a:
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        if item[0] == a[i][0]:
            break
        else:
            if item in b:
                continue
            else:
                b.append(item)
```

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/pcc/10$ python3 remove_help.py 
> [[1, 2], [1, 0], [2, 4], [3, 5]]
> [[2, 4], [3, 5]]
> ```

Achieved your goal no complex methods involed!
Enjoy!